# How can I insert image using URL?

Tags: java, image, swing, url

I have a table `product` with an image column.  I want to put image in some URL (not filesystem).

I already know how I can insert image in filesystem with this code here:

[image]

What I want is to insert image on remote system using URL because even the database I want to use it as remote database.

Comment: Don't (try to) post images of text! Instead include the text as an [edit] to the question. By the way, when editing, remove the Swing tag (which has nothing to do with inserting images in a database) and add the [tag:url], [tag:image] & [tag:database] tags, which actually seem **relevant.**

Comment: This question is completely unreadable. I appreciate that English might not be your first language, but you really need to try a little harder - nobody is going to be able to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Post code, preferably a [mcve], not _pictures_ of code.